# How to depend length of Rijndael function output from input length?

Tags: php, aes, rijndael

I have  function:

```
function aes_encrypt($value, $key) {
    return base64_encode(Security::rijndael($value, $key, 'encrypt'));
}
```

`Security::rijndael` from cakephp Security component, which implement Rijndael  256-bit key encryption.

I've store encrypted data in database, so I need to know how to depend the length of output from input.

Comment: if you mean [link]Format-preserving encryption(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) i think you should use AES in ECB mode.

Comment: @NoobTom thank you, interesting.  Really, I need to know dependence length of output from length of input.  I make several experiments, but I think it will be  better to know some theoretical relation.